# Beautifulsoup Findall() returns empty list []

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Im learning Web Scraping, I've writen a code to get the `<li>` list of connectors:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


html_text = requests.get('https://www.workato.com/integrations/salesforce').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text,'lxml')

apps = soup.find_all('span', {'class':'adapter-list__item-name'})

print(soup)
```

but I just got the empty value

```
[]
```

What should I do to improve my code?

Comment: There seems to be some JavaScripts on the page, which are rendering the content after page load, you may want to have a look at 'requests_html' module.

Answer (score 0):

These elements are loaded by JavaScript file, try this code:

```
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

url = 'https://cdn.marie.awsprod.workato.com/mktg-assets/c8ce8de9.js'

html_doc = requests.get(url).text
data = re.search(r'JSON\.parse\(\'(.*?)\'\)', html_doc).group(1)

data = literal_eval(data)

for i in data.values():
    print (count,i['title'])
```